# Get routes from database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How to load routes from database?
I have table **Post** with column :url. There is part of the url in this column, e.g.:

- about
- progs/us
- progs/us/info
- empty
- etc.

How to set routes for this? Result example:

```
http://mysite.com/progs/us for the page http://mysite/posts/2
```

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Routes are defined in the `config/routes.rb` file. Are you trying to match part of the url to a column in your database?

Comment: I'm still not sure. Are you trying to do something like FriendlyID? Check out this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can intercept any url by this route:

```
    # routes.rb
    get '*url' => 'posts#show', format: false
```

Note: this route should be declared last in your config

And controller looks like following:

```
    # posts_controller.rb
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
      def show
        @post = Post.find_by_url!(params[:url])
        # by default "show" view is rendered with "post" variable
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made routes like this

```
www.example.com/jenny250
www.example.com/bob1985
```

At **end** of routes.rb

```
get ':username' => 'users#show'
```

In the users controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  # ...
end
```